# Voting rate for my answers seems to have 'suddenly' changed

Tags: discussion

*A quick review relevant questions turned up one about general voting trends but nothing quite like what I'm asking here.*

Looking over my reputation history, I've noticed a change in the last month in the voting rate for my answers.  I see that as of December 2016, and prior, I was getting a pretty steady stream upvotes, that were trickling in about every 1-4 days, and on some days, two or more votes.

Lately, I've only been predominately only seeing votes for *new* answers.  One day, recently I saw some votes coming in for a couple of older answers, but the trend seems to have made a precipitous change across the board. I thought I noticed a change recently but it hasn't been improving for a couple of weeks or so since I first pointed it out, which seems to defy logic or, at least stands inexplicably in stark variance with a fairly long time trend.

Given the variety of types of answers at least within one category, it seems unlikely that suddenly virtually all interest would fall off seemingly all at once.

What could be going on, besides paranoia, and post election anxiety, and the SERP/page visibility aspect? I assume the pages are still similarly indexed by Google but maybe there's some sea change people with access to the analytics can see. Is there any chance that SO's vote tallying software has a bug or some kind of filtering is taking place?

It's all speculation in the dark because only thing I can validate is a change in activity. I haven't been developing in iOS recently, and  newer answers are not likely to be a source of ongoing rep because they've been mostly helping noobs, so only they and perhaps lurkers at the time of the answer are likely to vote and that's probably the end of it.

Comment: Have you looked at your [graph](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2079103/clearlight?tab=reputation&sort=graph)? Drag the translucent box to zoom.

Comment: @trashgod - I didn't say I'm getting fewer votes overall - I'm definitely getting more votes now because I've been very active recently, but as I mentioned, the votes I'm getting are predominantly for the new answers, with a distinct fall-off of incoming votes for older (and my more popular) answers. I will try to analyze the data more crisply and reply with an update as I find the time. I'm curious about what's going on and that graph doesn't break it down by question, or question age, etc....

Comment: I have just only over half the points that you do, but in my two years on this site my experience has been that I very rarely get any votes on my answers except within a few days of posting them. Perhaps it is a difference between the tags we tend to answer on. Perhaps the behaviour of people on the tags you follow is changing.

Comment: @Blackwood - Maybe people are writing iOS apps less now? Don't know. I can't rule it out but it seems unlikely. I need to find a way to graph the date by question and question age. If it was just one area within iOS and there was a new API or something that would be easier to assume.  But it seems my older questions in general have fallen off all at once. But getting more data would help increase my objectivity. I'm basing it on recent changes I perceived and then lightly verified by looking at my rep history for the past month or so.

Comment: I agree that it would be good to see that kind of data (hence my +1). I'm just saying that, purely from my point of view, it is the earlier behaviour (steady stream of votes) that seems unusual.

Comment: @Blackwood - I'm sure you're right. It depends on the tag and for C and bash and other areas most of the low hanging fruit has been picked. Hard to get traction. The right amount of specialization in a high traffic tag is probably another story, but as you can see prior to my recent burst of heavy activity and fresh answers/votes there was a pretty consistent stream and that seems different. More days between something happening, across all my answers save the fresh ones.

Comment: I assume you can play with [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) to get data from your timeline, there's a bunch of queries existing to get inspiration from.

Comment: @Tensibai - I didn't know about that! That's great! You're a life saver, I was about to write some ruby code to parse and crunch requests like this. http://stackoverflow.com//ajax/users/2079103/rep/day/1485907200?sort=post&amp;StartDate=2017-02-09